# Не работает код, возможно оператор switch

Tags: javascript, html

Делаю калькулятор, который будет считать формулами и столкнулся с тем что при запуске любой `function` все прекрасно работает, но после этого всего `alert(result)` **НЕ РАБОТАЕТ!**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>WDC</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/css.css">
    <script src="JavaScript/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="area(width, height)">AREA</button>
    <button onclick="perm(width, height)">perimetr</button>
    <button onclick="sizes(a)">size of square</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Js:

```
var height
var width
var a
function result(){
    var result = prompt("want to see result?")
}

//площадь//

function area(width, height) {
    prompt("height")
    prompt("width?")
    result()

    switch (result) {
        case "y":
            alert(height * width)
            break;
        case "n":
            alert("ok")
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

//периметр//

function perm(width, height) {
    prompt("height")
    prompt("width?")
    result()

    switch (result) {
        case "y":
            alert(height + width * 2)
            break;
        case("n"):
            alert("ok")
        break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

//объем куба //

function sizes(a) {
    prompt("verge")
    result()

    switch (result) {
        case "y":
            alert(a * 3)
            break;
        case "n":
            alert("ok")
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

кому легче работать с файлами то вот [ссылка на архив](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ip2kadQyanF5shglRBn6jfBvMfGl-9RJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `result()` ничего не возвращает. В каждой отдельной функции `result` содержит, я полагаю, объект самой функции, но никак не `y` или `n`.

Comment: Попробуйте вывести в лог значение переменной `result` перед `switch`. А сюда лучше вставьте код, а не картинки. Тогда все могли бы попробовать.

Comment: "все прекрасно работает" - ничего не работает

Comment: используйте `console.log(result)` для вывода сообщения и `debugger` для запуска отладчика

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если по пунктам, то:

1. Функции `area(), perm(), size()` по факту не принимают никаких параметров, вызов их `onclick="area(width,height)"` не имеет смысла, так как на момент вызова этих данных нет и в помине.
2. Данные, вроде `width` вы пытаетесь получить в теле самой функции, вызывая блокирующую функцию `prompt()`, что само по себе не совсем правильно. Среда для работы скрипта JavaScript дает множество отличных возможностей для получения данных от пользователя. Например, с помощью `input type="number"`. Более того, результат вызова `prompt()` нигде не хранится. Поэтому я прописал:

   `let height = +prompt("height");`
   Где ввожу, локальную для функции переменную, которая будет принимать возвращаемый результат. Унарный оператор `+` преобразовывает полученную строку (по возможности) в число.
3. В теле функции `area()` и других вызывается функция `result()`, но результат ее вызова не принимается. А сама `result()` ничего и не возвращает. Более того, функция и предполагаемое возвращаемое имеет одно и то же имя `result`. Можно было объявить переменную `result` в глобальной области, но при попытке задать ей значение в теле одноименной функции (`result = prompt("want to see result?")`, произойдет конфликт имен и скрипт закончится ошибкой. Поэтому функции лучше называть какими-то действиями: getResult, countArea, doSomething, одним словом.
   В вашем же варианте, в части `switch (result)` переменная `result` хранит ссылку на функцию как объект.
   Поэтому я опять же ввожу локальную переменную `result`, в которую помещаю возвращаемое функцией `getResult()` значение. Хотя с таким же успехом можно коротко прописать `switch(getResult())`.
4. Сам по себе вызов `prompt()` для подтверждения вывода результата тоже сомнителен. Не предлагается вариантов `'y' or 'n'`, эту информацию можно узнать только из кода. Тогда уж лучше воспользоваться `confirm()`. Хотя ни prompt, ни confirm, ни alert совершенно пользоваться не стоит ни при каких обстоятельствах.

Не ругайте сильно. Я оставил логику автора, лишь привел к минимально рабочему варианту.

```js
function getResult(){
    return prompt("want to see result?"); // Возвращается значение, введенное пользователем
}

function area() {
    let height = +prompt("height"); // Принимаем значение, преобразовываем в Number и присваиваем переменной
    let width = +prompt("width?");
    let result = getResult(); // Принимаем, возвращаемое функцией, значение

    switch (result) {
        case "y":
            alert(height * width)
            break;
        case "n":
            alert("ok")
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="area()">AREA</button> <!--Сократил немного -->
```

Comment: С чего вы взяли что я буду ругаться, мне важна критика. Очень все подробно расписали. Чуть позже попробую переделать, ещё раз спасибо

Comment: А также я даже не подозревал что можно делать переменные в функции, ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо

Comment: @Grifer_FOx, это я про мастеров JS, чтобы они мой ответ не ругали. А ругать есть за что: получается, что этим кодом я потакаю дурному тону написания кода. Исходных данных я не знаю, но прежде всего думайте о пользовательском опыте. Переменные лучше и объявлять в функциях, глобальную область принято не засорять.

Comment: уже проверил на двух функциях, все работает вот результат - https://shotbi.com/mac9. Жалко что я ещё не совсем знаю что такое LET и Return, но так как в моём курсе который я выбрал нет этого, прийдется по-гуглить и узнать что-то новое)

Comment: понятно, но за "локальные функции" - отдельное спасибо

Comment: Локальные переменные. Переменные данной области видимости, за пределами функции они не видны.